# Get entire function as string / and transform string into function?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, function, delegates

I want to get an entire Python function and save it as string (for instance, Javascript can simply do `functionString = functionVar.toString()`.

Example:

```
#I defined a function with a body:
def someFunction(hey):
    return hey + hey + hey
```

I want to convert this function to string and get exactly the same text as I typed above (without the comment, of course)

Then I want to do the inverse operation: from the string, convert it to a function and and store it in a variable to be called.

Comment: Take a look here: [Is there an easy way to pickle a python function (or otherwise serialize its code)?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1253528)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `exec` you can almost get what you're asking. Encoding the function as a string is the easy part.

```
"""Encode the function as a string"""
import inspect

funcString = inspect.getsource(someFunction)
```

Retrieving the function from the string is a touch more work. The following approach will have issues with globals or other variables outside the scope of the function you're trying to recover, but if the source completely specifies it then the following idea should work.

```
d = {}
exec(funcString, d)
f = next(d[k] for k in d if k != '__builtins__')
```

After running, the code defined by the source used to generate `f` in the first place will be bound to the variable `f`.

Comment: No worries. Do happen to know how to do the same trick but preserve the context/scope of a live function?

Comment: Well, you can access the function's global scope with `func.__globals__` and its closure with `func.__closure__`, but it won't be easy to serialize those and re-create the function with the closure in place.